# How to explicitly convert date to string date in php for entering date field in oracle?

Tags: php, oracle

When I try to insert a record in to the oracle using oci8 extension, I'm getting invalid month error.

```
'29-12-2015'
```

But if I try:

```
'29-DEC-2015'
```

It works. What could be the problem? And how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you provide the code snippets, where you try to add it to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've explicitly set your session parameters you're probably using the database default date format; something like `DD-MON-RR`.

Check your session date formats using `select * from nls_session_parameters`.

To address your problem you can either:

- set your session to recognise the date format you want to use:

  ```
  alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ...
  ```
- or explicitly convert strings to dates in the statement:

  ```
  ... to_date('2015-01-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD') ...
  ```

Comment: Please note that default database format is far from being a universal standard (and, unlike MySQL, can be changed anyway).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yep, hence 'something like' :^)